# dont know why touch events triggered twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using Jquery Mobile, and my touch events are being triggered twice. At first I thought it might be an overlap between mouse events and touch events, but I tried to unbind mouse events on tablets/smartphones and the events are still being triggered twice.

Here is my code

```
//Tablet Features
            var eventType = {
                swipeleft: '-=100',
                swiperight: '+=100'
            }
            $('#navMenu').bind('swipeleft swiperight', 
                function(e) {
                    $('#prbBtnHolder').animate({left:eventType[e.type]});
                    //alert(e.type);
                }
            );

//Device Detection
        (function () {
            var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
            var isDevice = agent.match(/android/i);

            if (isDevice == 'android') {
                //alert(isDevice);
                $('*').unbind('mousedown').unbind('mouseout').unbind('mousemove').unbind('mouseup');
            }
        })();
```

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, please help if you have any ideas.

**UPDATE**

I managed to solve the problem locally by placing the touch handlers outside the `.ready()` method. However, when i run the page on the server, the double trigger happens again. Now I'm completely stumped. Why are two identical pages (literally *identical*) behaving differently locally and on the server?

Comment: If you use the `i` flag in your regex you do not need to use `toLowerCase()` because the `i` flag means that the regex will search case-insensitive.

Comment: Which touch events are being triggered twice? The only touch events in your posted code are the `swipeleft`/`swiperight` event handlers, do you mean those? I tested the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/B8PQn/1/ on my mobile phone (Android 2.3) and the swipe events worked as expected.

Comment: @Jasper--this is just one example of code. every event on the page is being triggered twice, and im not sure why. maybe there is some sort of overlap with jquery mobile?

Comment: What will be helpful to help you out is to see the code that binds the event handlers. And if you use `.trigger()` anywhere, also post that code. But the event handler bindings will be very helpful.

Comment: @Jasper--the double triggers started happening only when i included jquery mobile, and the above code is the only place i have binded jquery mobile handlers.

Comment: Could you post an example link? maybe http://jsfiddle.net if the one @Jasper included doesn't work? Version of jQuery, version of jQM, Errors in the console?

Comment: @PhillPafford--I've found that if I take out the `jqM` src out of the html document the problem goes away. When `jqM` is initialized a `ui-mobile-viewport` class is added to the `body` and several divs with a `ui-loader` class are added to the bottom. This may be the source of the problem? Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you binding to the `vclick` or any other vritual-mouse event that jQuery Mobile offers? If so then that's your issue.

Comment: @Jasper--no, in fact I have also unbinded `vclick` and every other virtual mouse event.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it with a little tweak around... I don't recommend this for the exact solution but my take you out of the problem fast.

I define a global Flag

```
var bDidPan=true;
```

and inside the trigger wrote the following:

```
if (bDidPan) {
  bDidPan = false; // IT'S IMPORTANT TO PUT THIS FIRST
  //code to execute when triggers
}
else
{
  bDidPan = true;
}
```

and that did the trick. You can do the trick with numbers (It worked better with numbers for me!)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like you're putting your scripts into the `<body>` tag. If you do that, they'll get run twice. I've had this very same thing happen and went a little balder for the trouble and frustration. Make sure all your scripts are inside the `<head>` tag.